# Query all rpm's installed as non-root?

Tags: installation, rpm

As the title states I would like to know how to list all rpms that have been installed after I've initialized my own db (I've browsed the man pages and googled but that didn't bring me fortune):

**rpm --initdb --root /home/username/local --dbpath /home/username/local/lib/rpm**

?

Executing **rpm -qa** will not show any packages in the local db above.

Best Regards,
Mr. Pistol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both `--root /home/username/local` and `--dbpath /home/username/local/lib/rpm` options on each invocation of rpm when you want to use user-installed database. Rpm always uses system database unless told otherwise.

**Note:** using both options seems excessive, since the database is created under root. In your case that would mean the database would be under `/home/username/local/home/username/local/lib/rpm`. I believe that was not your intention

Comment: Ok, so it should be **rpm --root /home/username/local --dbpath lib/rpm -qa**? That didn't return anything but I do believe I've installed Poco (all it's binary files are reachable under **/home/username/local/lib64/**). But since my knowledge of rpm is not a 100% I could be missing something here.

Comment: I know discovered that the dbpath I provided to this operation was wrong 0:-) With the right one it works perfectly. Thank you for your help! Have a nice day, Pistol